# Angular 5: get method with params and observe response

Tags: angular, parameters, get, httpclient

I want to make a get request with params and observe the whole response object instead of the body. But the get method only accepts two arguments. How can I achieve this?

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('q', 'cironunes');

this.http.get(server_utl, { params }, {observe:response});
```

Comment: Do you use `Http` or `HttpClient` ?

Comment: HttpClient from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter accept options which can have `params` and `observe`. So you can pass your data like this

```
this.http.get(server_utl, { params, observe: 'response' });
```

This is the signature of the method `get`

```
get(url: string, options: {...}): Observable<any>
```

and what can accept the `options` paraneter

```
headers?: HttpHeaders | {
    [header: string]: string | string[];
};
observe?: HttpObserve;
params?: HttpParams | {
    [param: string]: string | string[];
};
reportProgress?: boolean;
responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
withCredentials?: boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const params = new HttpParams();
params.set('key', 'value');
this.http.get(server_utl, {params, observe: 'response'});
```

You don't make GET requests with a body. The parameters are appended to the URL.